# Does nginx ingress able to export headless service?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, prometheus-operator

Does nginx ingress controller able to export a headless service?
The underlaying pod is using `hostNetwork`.

Is there documentation for this?

Specifically, I'm trying to export node-export service(manifest comes from `kube-prometheus`) by nginx ingress controller.

---

a short code of ingress:

```
...
       - path: /node-exporter
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           serviceName: node-exporter
           servicePort: 9100
...
```

---

a short code of service:

```
...
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 9100
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: node-exporter
...
```

Comment: In theory yes, headless service can be exposed with nginx ingress controller - though it is not pretty much recommended as per  [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). Could you please specify how exactly the ingress was configured?

Comment: Hello @anarxz, I don't see the document about kubernetes not recommended expose headless service... Which passage are you referring to? I post my code above. By the way, I realized that I don't need a service to expose because they are already exposed using `hostNetwork`.

Comment: I've posted my explanation as answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test result,

I can't export a hostNetwork service by ingress.

Here is my result matrix:

|  | headless | clusterIP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hostNetwork: True | 502 | 502 |
| hostNetwork: False | ✔ | ✔ |

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `headless Services`  are of the same type as default `ClusterIP`, which exposes Service on a cluster-internal IP -  the only difference is that `headless service` allows clients to connect to pod directly without proxy.
I was referring to this part in Kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), where it is stated that `ClusterIP` is supposed to be accessible only from within the cluster, while ingress would expose it outside of the cluster :

> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`.

As per  `hostNetwork`,  when it is set to `True`, a pod is granted [access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces) to the services listening on localhost, it can use the node network namespace and therefore see and use network interfaces of the host machine. In its turn, the pod would  be accessible on these network interfaces  and it can receive outside traffic directly.